# Generating variable observations for one id to be observation for new variable of another id

Tags: variables, stata

I have a data set that allows linking friends (i.e. observing peer groups) and thereby one can observe the characteristics of an individual's friends. What I have is an 8 digit identifier, id, each id's friend id's (up to 10 friends), and then many characteristic variables.

I want to take an individual and create a variables that are the foreign born status of each friend.

I already have an indicator for each person that is 1 if foreign born. Below is a small example, for just one friend. Notice, `MF1` means male friend 1 and then `MF1id` is the id number for male friend 1. The respondents could list up to 5 male friends and 5 female friends.

[image: example]

So, I need Stata to look at `MF1id` and then match it down the id column, then look over to f_born for that matched id, and finally input the value of `f_born` there back up to the original id under `MF1f_born`.

edit: I did a poor job of explaining the data structure. I have a cross section so 1 observation per unique id. Row 1 is the first 8 digit id number with all the variables following over the row. The repeating id numbers are between the friend id's listed for each person (mf1id for example) and the id column. I hope that is a bit more clear.

Comment: Lacking any sample data to play with, I'll limit myself to suggesting that the solution that comes to mind would make use of `merge` and most likely `reshape long`. The anthropomorphic solution you describe (Stata looks over, looks down, inputs back up to the original) is not, I hope, what you were planning on implementing but just a description of how a person, as opposed to Stata, might create the desired result.

Answer (score 1):

Kevin Crow wrote `vlookup` that makes this sort of thing pretty easy:

```
use http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/stata/faq/dyads, clear
drop team y
rename (rater ratee) (id mf1_id)
bys id: gen f_born = mod(id,2)==1

net install vlookup
vlookup mf1_id, gen(mf1f_born) key(id) value(f_born)
```

Comment: Good tip. `net install vlookup, from(http://www.stata.com/users/kcrow)` is how to install.

Comment: Previously unknown to me, even after a year of following Statalist and Stack Overflow. Nice, and it's always easier to take advantage of someone else's work than write your own. `view vlookup.ado` shows some very clean code, a good lesson in effective Stata.

Comment: Thanks all! I installed vlookup and looked over the help file provided with it in addition to Dimitriy's example. The example in the help file itself appears to do exactly what I am attempting to do. I put the following syntax in my do file

Comment: ooops....vlookup mf1_id, gen(mf1f_born) key(id) value(f_born) however stata gives me the following error message "f_born is unique within id; there are multiple observations with different f_born within id." Thus far I have not been able to figure out why this is occurring. Any suggestions? Thanks again, I appreciate the responses.

Comment: Ah one more thing. I did use duplicates report to check the id for any possible duplicates. None were found so that does not seem to be an issue.

Comment: @Jonathan I am guessing you have at least one id that is both foreign and domestic. I am not sure what duplicates command you ran, but you should certainly have duplicates of id if I understand your data structure. Try
`bys id: egen f_types = nvals(f_born)` followed by `edit if f_types > 1` to find the problematic observations.

Comment: I'm sorry I was confusing in my data structure description. I have edited the question attempting to clear that up. In brief, its a cross section, not a panel. I ran your suggestion above. It revealed missing observations so I dropped those and now the previous error is gone but stata now reports "invalid 'files' ". So, I pulled your example code and ran it, but I get the same response: invalid files. I have checked vlookup is installed and Stata reports it is.

Comment: Interestingly, I can pull the data from ucla in just fine and generate the f_born variable as you did but once vlookup is ran, boom problem. I have doubled, tripled, quadrupled checked the syntax and it is an exact match with yours. Frustrating. I am using Stata 13.

Comment: It will be hard to diagnose without seeing your data and what you types. In any case, I just ran it in 13.1 without any problems. `vlookup` is from 2003, so it should be OK in Stata 13. If you use `viewsource vlookup.ado` command you can see what it is doing under the hood. Maybe you can run that code and see where the invalid file error pops up. An alternative is to `set trace on ` before the `vlookup step` and note where the error happens.

Comment: I was finally able to figure out the problem using set trace on as you suggested. The error was occurring within the program for vlookup where it attempted to save some data manipulations to the temp folder. I'm not sure why this is occurring exactly, but my data security agreement requires me to point all stata temp files to a very specific folder on a secure drive. It could be something in this process is causing a problem. Anyways I will post a follow up showing how I made some small tweaks to the vlookup program and got the result I need.

Answer (score 0):

So, Dimitriy's suggestion of vlookup is perfect except it will not work for me. After trying vlookup with both my data set, the UCLA data that Dimitriy used for his example, and a toy data set I created vlookup always failed at the point the program attempts to save a temp file to my temp folder. Below is the program for vlookup. Notice its sets tempfile file, manipulates the data, and then saves the file.

```html
*! version 1.0.0 KHC 16oct2003
program define vlookup, sortpreserve
 version 8.0
 syntax varname, Generate(name) Key(varname) Value(varname)
 qui {
  tempvar g k
  egen `k' = group(`key')
  egen `g' = group(`key' `value')
  local k = `k'[_N]
  local g = `g'[_N]
  if `k' != `g' {
   di in red "`value' is unique within `key';"
   di in red /*
   */ "there are multiple observations with different `value'" /*
   */ " within `key'."
   exit 9
  }
  preserve
   tempvar g _merge
   tempfile file
   sort `key'
   by `key' : keep if _n == 1
   keep `key' `value'
   sort `key'
   rename `key'  `varlist'
   rename  `value' `generate'
   save `file', replace
  restore
  sort `varlist'
  joinby `varlist' using `file', unmatched(master) _merge(`_merge')
  drop `_merge'

 }
end
exit
```

For some reason, Stata gave me an error, "invalid file," at the save `file', replace point. I have a restricted data set with requirments to point all my Stata temp files to a very specific folder that has an erasure program sweeping it every so often. I don't know why this would create a problem but maybe it is, I really don't know. Regardless, I tweaked the vlookup program and it appears to do what I need now.

```html
clear all
set more off
capture log close


input aid mf1aid fborn
   1   2      1
   2   1   1
   3   5      0
   4   2      0
   5   1      0
   6   4      0
   7   6      1
   8   2      .
   9   1      0
   10  8      1
end  


program define justlinkit, sortpreserve
 syntax varname, Generate(name) Key(varname) Value(name)
 qui {
preserve 
 tempvar g _merge
 sort `key'
 by `key' : keep if _n ==1
 keep `key' `value'
 sort `key'
 rename `key' `varlist'
 rename `value' `generate'
 save "Z:\Jonathan\created data sets\justlinkit program\fchara.dta",replace
restore
sort `varlist'
joinby `varlist' using "Z:\Jonathan\created data sets\justlinkit program\fchara.dta", unmatched(master) _merge(`_merge')
drop `_merge'

 }
end

// set trace on
justlinkit mf1aid, gen(mf1_fborn) key(aid) value(fborn)

sort aid 
list
```

Well, this fixed my problem. Thanks to all who responded I would not have figured this out without you.

Comment: Your filepaths evidently include spaces. Hence references to the local holding the temporary file name should be in double quotes `""`, just as you have done for the real filename you used.

Comment: Ah, indeed that is probably why vlookup wasn't working. Good catch. Sloppy on my part.

Comment: If I am right, it is really surprising that such a bug has not been tickled before.

Comment: You might be able to set your tmp directory to point to your special folder like [this](http://www.stata.com/support/faqs/data-management/statatmp-environment-variable/).